# How to count and group by combinations of multiple columns?

Tags: sql, combinations

For a table such as:

```
foo_table

id | str_col | bool_col

 1   "1234"     0
 2   "3215"     0
 3   "8132"     1
 4   NULL       1
 5   ""         1
 6   ""         0
```

I know how to query both of:

```
count(*) | bool_col
   3          0
   3          1
```

and

```
count(*) | isnull(str_col) or str_col = ""
   3          0
   3          1
```

but how could I get something like:

```
count(*) | bool_col | isnull(str_col) or str_col = ""
   2          0           0
   1          0           1
   1          1           0
   2          1           1
```

In the meantime, I'm just individually doing:

```
select count(*) from foo_table where bool_col and (isnull(str_col) or str_col = "");
select count(*) from foo_table where not bool_col and (isnull(str_col) or str_col = "");
select count(*) from foo_table where bool_col and not (isnull(str_col) or str_col = "");
select count(*) from foo_table where not bool_col and not (isnull(str_col) or str_col = "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       bool_col, 
       CASE WHEN str_col IS NULL OR str_col = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END str_col
  FROM foo_table
 GROUP BY bool_col, 
       CASE WHEN str_col IS NULL OR str_col = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Output (MySql):

```
| COUNT(*) | BOOL_COL | STR_COL |
---------------------------------
|        2 |        0 |       0 |
|        1 |        0 |       1 |
|        1 |        1 |       0 |
|        2 |        1 |       1 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0f67/14)** MySQL

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c359/3)** SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE 
 WHEN bool_col AND (isnull(str_col) or str_col = "")  THEN 1 
END) as c1,
COUNT(CASE 
 WHEN not bool_col and (isnull(str_col) or str_col = "") THEN 1
END) as c2,
COUNT(CASE 
 WHEN bool_col and not (isnull(str_col) or str_col = "") THEN 1
END) as c3,
COUNT(CASE 
 WHEN not bool_col and not (isnull(str_col) or str_col = "") THEN 1
END) as c4
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle there is a build in function for that called `cube`

```
select  bool_col , 
        case when str_col is null or str_col = '' then 1 else 0 end str_col ,
        count(*)
from    table1
group by cube (bool_col , case when str_col is null or str_col = '' then 1 else 0 end)
```

`cube` will give you all combination. there is also `rollup` which is a private case of `cube`.